# spring-cloud-stream-binder-Kafka should depend on the core spring-Kafka for common functionality

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I search inside spring-Kafka for **interactive query** and I did not find it.

On the other side, I find such a service in **spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka**.

At the end **spring-cloud-stream-binder-Kafka** should depend on the core **spring-Kafka** and not the 
opposite.

Please note I know it is easy to write such a service but my concern for two things:

*a) why this feature does not exist in **spring Kafka core**?*

*b) why the common features not inherited from spring-Kafka core?*

Answer (score 0):

kafka-streams is an optional dependency in spring-kafka because not everybody wants it. Just add the jar to your dependencies.